# My render set to 1000 cycles is not crystal clear

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I created a donut and cup in blender. I went into Render-Sampling and clicked on "Render" and set it to 1000. yeah, it was over kill, but it should be crystal clear. After 11 hours of rendering (no joke) it was crystal clear, of course, but the cup and half the donut as well had grain still! I already rendered it. I do not have photoshop. anyway to fix this? I am a beginner at blender, and i used my GPU to render it. any help is appreciated!

picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMecx.png

only took a couple hours :)

zoom in near the cup....

Comment: Some images and/or a .blend file would be helpful. You can upload a .blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: what if it is a png?

Comment: i've just finished rendering it

Comment: check out this link, this is going to be helpful if render glass or refractive shaders https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOkLnfyuXTAhXH0RoKHcdwCcQQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.blenderguru.com%2Farticles%2F7-ways-get-rid-fireflies%2F&usg=AFQjCNEeXF2p2kthndwKwSpugQbXtdRtxw&sig2=FFcjS6ne5rcJYYRXXvHBBA

Comment: You will have to upload your png in order for someone to help you.

Comment: it says to upload a .blend file. i only have a png...

Comment: If you edit your question, you can insert the image right here. There is a button to upload it.

Comment: What are your material, and render settings? How large are your light sources? It would be useful if you add at least that bit of information, if not a simplified version of the file (please pack textures via *file>external data>pack all into .blend* if uploading a file) by an edit to your question.

Answer (score -1):

It´s never completely noise-free.
I rendered my latest projekt with 8192 samples and at some Points there is still grain (But it took just 1 hour to render, not really complicated lighting/mesh)

But as Benjaming J. already wrote, you can follow this link https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/
Some tips are really helpful actually.

I also decreased render time on my latest Little Project(Yamaha HS7 Speaker) by Rendering the part of the Picture that tends to be noisier with a higher sample rate(For example the left part of the Picture where the Speaker stands). (This doesnt work with animations of Course)